# Javascript distance between points without parsing whole array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I have a quick question.
Just before I begin I just want to say I am not writing the examples in any specific language
But for the project itself I am using javascript
I have an array

```
var boxes = [];
```

And an array of players

```
var players = [];
```

both player and box are objects of

```
{x: centerX, y: centerY, r: radius}
```

I think that the only way to check if any player collided with any box (and dect which with which) I have to do something like

```
for player in players
    for box in boxes
       # collision check
```

Is there any way of making it more efficient?
I realise that parsing through for example 1000 players and 1000 boxes would take a lot of time.

My friend thinks there should be somthing like sonar in real life, that would detect the box lets say up to 200 pixels in front of player

Is there anything like that?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't much detail here. What attributes does a box have? What attributes do the players have?

Comment: you could include some example of boxes and players.

Comment: Basically it is just an object with positions x and y

Comment: You could insert the boxes into a spatial hierarchy structure, e.g. quad-tree, and test each player at O(log(boxes)).

Answer (score 0):

you could have coordinates of all map pixels and just when box/player moves update that x is in (x;y) location and for collision detection just check if there are more than 1 items in this location, if so - collision.

But this forum is not for game developers, you should ask such question at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

You could make use of array functions to improve it.

`const hasCollision = players.reduce((acc, player) => acc || boxes.some(box => player.x === box.x), false);`